# How do you implement a if/else statement in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that updates as a player moves around tiles. Currently the stored procedure works and the table updates as the player moves, but I want to add multi-user feature that does not update the row if there is already a value in a column.

| tileID | tilePlayer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | null |
| 4 | Player1 |

Currently I can move to another tile like this (Moves from tileID 4 to tileID 3):

| tileID | tilePlayer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | Player1 |
| 4 | null |

But I want to make it so that it doesnt move to tileID 3 if there is a player on it

| tileID | tilePlayer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | Player2 |
| 4 | Player1 |

So, if tileID 3 = null ~ It will update to player1

and if tileID 3= player2 ~ it will not update and player2 will stay as tileID 3 and player1 will stay as tileID 4

Here is my stored procedure that updates the position:

```
create procedure UpdateDataTile()
    BEGIN
UPDATE  tbl_tile SET tilePlayer = null WHERE tilePlayer = "player1";

UPDATE  tbl_tile t 
INNER JOIN
tbl_player p 
ON t.tileID = p.tileID 
SET t.tilePlayer = uname;

    END//
delimiter ;
```

Essentially I want to implement a statement that does something like this:

```
create procedure UpdateDataTile(IN `uname` varchar(100), `tileVal` int)
    BEGIN
    
If {
tbl_tile row 3 (or whatever is +1 or -1 current tilePlayer row) column tilePlayer != null {return}
}
else
DO this{
UPDATE  tbl_tile SET tilePlayer = null WHERE tilePlayer = uname;

UPDATE  tbl_tile t 
INNER JOIN
tbl_player p 
ON t.tileID = p.tileID 
SET t.tilePlayer = uname;
}
    END//
delimiter ;
```

I understand that I cant to if/else statement like I would in c# etc, but is there a way I could implement this?

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: I had a look at it, but am not sure how I could implement it